# Deserializing JArray

Tags: arrays, json, json.net

I have a JSON Array having below format:

```
array =
[ 
  {
    "Key1": "Value11", "Key2": "Value21", Key3: "Value31", "Key4": ["Value41”]
  },
  {
    "Key1": "Value12", "Key2": "Value22", Key3: "Value32", "Key4": ["Value42"]
  }
]
```

I am using JSON.NET for deserializing it like below:

```
dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(array.ToString());
```

But I am getting error because of Value41 & Value42 are in square bracket. Can you please tell me how can I get each Key Value pair?

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: How can I make leppie's comment as answer? So I can mark it

Comment: Post the answer (yourself) and mark as solution == REP for you :)